# Hide source code from public view in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Hi I am using WSO2 integrator for my integration projects. I would like to know that, is there a way to hide the source codes deployed in WSO2 as car file.That is, the user should not be allowed to edit the services either in source view or in design view. Also please share the thoughts of customize wso2 itself for the same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create users and assign different permission for users in ESB. You can see in the following documentation how to add users and configure roles:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+Roles

To add a user On the Main tab in the management console, click Add under Users and Roles and follow along.

The following will help to set permissions:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Role-based+Permissions

Comment: If we deploy the car file in wso2 is it possible to lock the car file so that the services are not visible to anyone and expire or delete car after some days like licensing.